# What's the quickest way to assign a variables based on an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration, assign

What's the quickest way, from a readability/typing standpoint, to assign a value to a specific variable based on a related variable?

```
var abbrev;

if(state=='Pennsylvania'){
    abbrev='PA';
}else if(state=='New Jersey'){
    abbrev='NJ';
}else if(state=='Delaware'){
    abbrev='DE';
}
//and so on...
```

I'm trying to avoid making one array for the state name and a another array for the abbreviation because the relationship is lost with separate declarations.

Comment: Use a `Map` (`Object` in JS). Then you can have string keys point at string values (eg: `obj['Pennsylvania'] = 'PA'`)

Comment: You need **some** way to associate state to abbreviation, so your best bet probably actually an associative array. The 'best' option is subjective, and depends on what you personally consider 'best'. The four options are basically an if/else statement, a switch statement, an associative array, or mapping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for the abbreviation, like

```
var abbreviations = {
        'Pennsylvania': 'PA',
        'New Jersey': 'NJ',
        'Delaware': 'DE'
    };
```

Usage:

```
abbrev = abbreviations[state];
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

just a suggestion, have you tried using CASE? it looks more clean and readable

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
var abbrev = '';
    if(state.indexOf(' ') == -1){
    abbrev = state.substring(0,2).toUpperCase();
    }else{
    var firstLetter = state.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
    var secoundLetter = state.substring(state.indexOf(' '),1).toUpperCase();
    abbrev = firstLetter  + secoundLetter;
    }
    alert(abbrev);
```

Comment: This doesn&#39;t work for states like pennsylvania or texas which consist of one word.

Comment: Lets start at the [beginning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._state_abbreviations)... `Alaska:AK`

Comment: I am Brazilian, I do not know the American states, in my case, this code works: Acre - AC, Alagoas - AL, Amazonas - AM, São Paulo - SP, Bahia - BA, Belo Horizonte - BH, Minas Gerais - MG, Etc ... ;)